# How do you get a rectangle to move away from the mouse?

Tags: javafx, game-development

I am trying to write code that has a rectangle on my screen that whenever the mouse gets near it, the rectangle moves away from the mouse by a small amount. It'll be almost as if you're pushing the box with the mouse. So far I've only been able to get the box to move to the left whenever I move my mouse.

```
package boxcode;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class boxcode extends Application {


public static void main(String [] args){

launch(args);
}

 @Override
 public void start(Stage stage) {

Rectangle box = new Rectangle(20,20);
box.setTranslateX(200);
box.setTranslateY(60);
Group root = new Group(box);
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 320, 240);

box.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
{
@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent event)
{
box.setTranslateX(box.getTranslateX() - 5);
}
});

stage.setTitle("Game Dev");
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();

}

}
```

Comment: Write down in detail what is happening and then try to code that. Example: What happens when the mouse approaches the rectangle from the left? What direction will the rectangle move in? What happens if the mouse approaches the rectangle from the top? Which direction will the rectangle go in? Now, think about it coming from any direction. What direction would the rectangle go in? Do you know about vectors and forces? Here is an excellent free book on the subject. They have an example where particles are attracted to the mouse pointer.  https://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-1-vectors/

Comment: FYI: You should not be using `AWT` imports for the mouse events.

Comment: It also sounds like you want to respond to the mouse moving when it is *not* over the rectangle. To do that, you’ll need a mouse listener on the `Group`, not on the `Rectangle`.